# .toggle() not setting display to none?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whilst creating a jQuery dropdown menu i ran in to a most peculiar problem - an element that has been hidden is still affecting the page. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? It is affecting the functionality by blocking part of the button, forcing one to call the function from a unblocked part. For example;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#start").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#box").stop().toggle();
    $("#box").stop().animate({
      top:'50px',
      opacity:'1'
    },400,function(){
    });
  });
  $("#start").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#box").stop().animate({
      top:'25px',
      opacity:'0'
    },400,function(){
    $("#box").stop().toggle();
    });
  });
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<button id="start">Start Animation</button>
<div id ="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;opacity:0;display:none;top:25px;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** set the top setting to ten px to completely cover up the button if you can't see the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: The function will not fire because the element is over it. This should not be occurring because the element is hidden.

Comment: [Looks fine](http://jsfiddle.net/h6fem7pt/). Or can you be more specific?

Comment: What I am getting at is that I can't reproduce the problem, so either the problem is somewhere beyond the code you've posted or you are not explaining the problem in enough detail (or both).

Comment: Try setting the top to 10, you will see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfodjxju/) where the problem is solved using `z-index:-1;` for the div. When this z-index is removed, the mouseenter of the button is not working for the lower part of the button because the animated div, though not visible, covers part of the button.